# Creating fixed length numeric string

Tags: c#, string

I have a certain number of files for which I need the filenames in my program. The files have a fixed naming fashion i.e. (prefix + digits).jpg. For e.g.: `head001.jpg`, `head002.jpg`, `head003.jpg` etc. etc.

The number of digits, in the end, can be varying - so the program has variables to change where the file naming starts from, where it ends and how many number digits are used in the naming. For e.g: A second scenario could be - `tail00001.jpg`, `tail00002.jpg`, `tail00003.jpg` etc. until `tail00100.jpg` 
And in this case: start digit would be 0, end digit would be 100 and numDigits would be 5

In C++, I’ve seen this formatting being done as follows:
`format <<prefix<<"%0"<<numDigits<<"d."<<filetype;` //where `format` is a `stringstream`

However, I’m not quite sure about the best way to do this in C# and would like to know how to solve this.

Comment: String.Format is your friend. MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Or `ToString`: `myIntValue.ToString("D8");` //8 means total length of output string

Comment: @SBI : Can you point to the constructor or the function or the format literals to use to maintain fixed length of numeric string with `String.Format`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `string.Format`, with a *precision specifier* saying how many digits you want:

```
string name = string.Format("tail{0:d6}.jpg", index);
```

See the MSDN documentation for [standard numeric string formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

You can build the string format up programmatically of course:

```
string name = string.Format("tail{0:d" + digits + "}.jpg", index);
```

Or use `PadLeft` as suggested by Vano. You might still want to use `string.Format` though:

```
string name = string.Format("tail{0}.jpg",
                            index.ToString().PadLeft(digits, '0'));
```

Using `PadLeft` has the advantage that it's easier to change the padding value, although I would imagine you'd always want it to be `0` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

string has *PadLeft* method:

```
int n1 = 1;
string t1 = n1.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0'); // This will return 00001
int n10 = 10;
string t2 = n10.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0'); // This will return 00010 and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

> ..and in this case: start digit would be 0, end digit would be 100 and
>   numDigits would be 5

You could use [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [decimal format/precision specifier "D"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100).aspx#DFormatString) and a for-loop:

```
int start = 0;
int end = 100;
int numDigits = 5;
string name = "tail";
string extension = ".jpg";
for(int i = start; i <= end; i++)
{
    string fileName = string.Format(
        "{0}{1}{2}", name, i.ToString("D" + numDigits), extension);
    Console.WriteLine(fileName);
}
```

Outputs:

```
tail00000.jpg
tail00001.jpg
tail00002.jpg
tail00003.jpg
tail00004.jpg
tail00005.jpg
tail00006.jpg
tail00007.jpg
tail00008.jpg
tail00009.jpg
tail00010.jpg
....
tail100.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using string.Format

```
var result = string.Format("{0}{1:00000}{2}", prefix, number, filetype)
```

Or you could use padleft

```
var result = prefix + number.ToString().PadLeft('0', numDigits) + "." + extension;
```

Or you can use a mix of the two :)

Answer (score 0):

**For modern .NET 5.0+** (2021 update)

```
int myint = 100;
string zeroPadded = $"{myint:d8}";      // "00000100"
string spacePadded = $"{myint,8}";      // "     100"
```